# How to programatically set BottomNavigationView background colour at run time

Tags: android, android-layout, android-resources, bottomnavigationview

I have a `BottomNavigationView*` tab bar, and I want to set the background colour, however I don't have the colour until runtime. It appears as though `setItemBackground` requires a resource id.

Is there some way of creating a resource out of a `GradientDrawable` or something similar, then passing that new resource id?

Alternatively is there some other way of doing this without using XML that I've missed and would allow me to just pass a colour or `Drawable`?

It seems weird that this is so difficult...

*actually using `BottomNavigationViewEx` which is an extension of it from here, but it doesn't make much difference to my question: https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BottomNavigationViewEx` inherits from `View`, which has a `setBackground(Drawable drawable)` method. Use that if you're trying to set the background. If you want to change the background of the items, you will have to either subclass or create a custom implementation of `BottomNavigationViewEx` as it doesn't look like it supports dynamically generated resources. But I don't see anything prohibiting such a thing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how it is done in `BottomNavigationView` or even if it is possible(at least I didn't find anything in the docs that point out for an easy solution) but personally, I have also tried `AHBottomNavigation` and it seems more complete. It also gives you the possibility of achieving what you want with:

```
bottomNavigation.setDefaultBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FEFEFE"));
```

Link to git project: [HERE](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation)

Comment: The other solution is more straightforward, but I will bear this alternative navigation bar in mind in case I need to change in future, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity you can directly use such as:

> bottomNavigationView.setItemBackgroundResource((R.color.colorxyz));

Hope this works for you.